# css + Android - no click response on scrollable/List view

Tags: android, css, click, overflow, scrollview

I have a very Long List in my WebApplication generated dynamically with JQuery Mobile.
My Problem here is, i can't click on any Item of this scrollable view. I can hear the sound when I click on an Item, but there is no response. And I have this issue only on Android. On iOS everything is working fine.
The Problem seems to be something with overflow: auto/scroll in css. An issue, that is known since 2009. The strange thing here is, I don´t have a Problem with scrolling. It´s really working fine. Touch events just doesn´t responding. Any Idea?

Im using Android 4.x, Phonegap 2.4 and JQueryMobile 1.3

Comment: Best add your solution as an answer, rather than an edit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. My Problem was, the Parent Div had no height.